# Why does knuth mastermind algorithm favour guesses in S?

Tags: algorithms

From [wikipedia : Mastermind > algorithms:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29#Five-guess_algorithm)

> From the set of guesses with the maximum score select one as the next guess, choosing a member of S whenever possible.

I understand that the hidden code is in S, so it makes sense to choose a guess in S over one that couldn't possibly win in the next turn. But, is this the ONLY reason that this step is necessary? or does it have a more important purpose?

Answer (score 0):

As the Wikipedia article goes on to say

> Knuth also gives an example showing that in some cases no member of $S$ will be among the highest scoring guesses and thus the guess cannot win on the next turn, yet will be necessary to assure a win in five.

Other things being equal, a guess in $S$ is likely to be better than a guess outside $S$ with the same score measured against remaining possibilities; as you say, you could then win on the next turn.  But [Knuth's original article](http://www.cs.uni.edu/%7Ewallingf/teaching/cs3530/resources/knuth-mastermind.pdf) said on page 3 about $1462$ that the score is more important than being in $S$, if your aim is to assure a win in five guess overall, and Knuth's aim was to show his algorithm never did worse than that.

That does not mean Knuth's algorithm was *best* in every sense, and he showed that it was not. There are other algorithms with a lower expected number of guesses than Knuth's, but a worst-case number of guesses of six.